# Coinbase API revoke token

Tags: api, oauth, token, coinbase-api

Is there any way to revoke coinbase oauth token? Coinbase documentation says that token is revoked after 2 hours, but I want my users to revoke access at any time they want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this through the API, but you could link your users to https://coinbase.com/applications where they can revoke access themselves.

Comment: Maybe, they'll add revoke support through API. It's not cool for me to send my customers to another site

Answer (score 0):

This is now allegedly supported (https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/access-and-refresh-tokens), **but it does not work**.

Answer (score 0):

The access token can be revoked with the `https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/revoke` endpoint. Here is a curl request on how to use it:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/revoke' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'token=ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

Or with Node.js ([Source](https://saasbase.dev/api-reference-coinbase-using-oauth2-node-js?source=so)):

```
app.get('/refreshToken', async (req, res) => {
  const data = qs.stringify({
    'token': 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
  });
  const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/revoke',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'
    },
    data
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios(config);
    res.send({ response: response?.data })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Could not refresh token", e.response.data)
  }
})
```